# What is the role of identifier in C preprocessor directives

Tags: c, macros, preprocessor

When I execute the following code, the output is `5 6`.

```
int main()
{
    int one = 5, two = 6;
    #ifdef next
    one = 2;
    two = 1;
    #endif
        printf("%d %d", one, two);
    return 0;
}
```

Definitely the code within `#ifdef #endif` is not getting excuted.
I am unable to understand the utility of the identifier `next`. What is the keyword instead of `next` that will make the compiler execute the code inside the `#ifdef #endif` section?

[reference](https://geeksforgeeks.org/cpp-preprocessor-directives-set-2/)

Comment: I'd be really careful about using a macro name that is short, common and in lower case. The resulting confusion can be maddening. Customarily, macro names are in ALL_CAPS to reduce the likelihood of name collisions.

Comment: @FredLarson: `next` is a bad name, but all capital letters is archaic. It stems from a time of limited character sets and identifier lengths. For many macros, there is no practical reason the style for for a macro constant should be different from the style for a `static const int` or an `enum`: To its user, it is merely a symbol for some constant or configuration value, and that is what its name should convey.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: I'd say one reason is scope. A badly named macro will tear through a whole translation unit wreaking havoc, totally unware of scope. It could be argued macros themselves are largely archaic (well, at least in C++. Perhaps less so in C). Where they are still useful, I like them to stand out a much as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply define the macro

```
#define next
int main()
{
    int one = 5, two = 6;
    #ifdef next
    one = 2;
    two = 1;
    #endif
        printf("%d %d", one, two);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the values will change.